# Disable persistence of FirebaseUI Firestore failed

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have switched off the mobile network and setPersistenceEnabled to false(disable the cache).
Then add the data to Firestore by calling add().

The add() operation is success and the data is showed on the screen by FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.(The mobile network is still disconnected).

Is the behavior correct ? I think the add() operation should be failed and nothing to show on the screen due to connection lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected behavior.  Whenever you change a document, the Firestore SDK broadcasts that change for local listeners, regardless of your settings for local persistence.  The local change is visible to listeners without any need for a network connection.  When the network becomes available again, the local change will be synchronized.

When persistence is disabled, that means local changes are not saved to disk.  In that case, when your app process is killed, any changes that you made locally will be completely lost.

This behavior doesn't have anything to do with Firebase UI specfically. It's a a core behavior of the Firestore SDK.